# Why in javascript filtering an object of a class that extends an Array calls it's constructor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, derived-class, es6-class

I have this example code:

```js
class TestClass extends Array {
 constructor() {
  console.log( 'constructor' );
  
  let ar = [];
  ar.push( { id: 1, name: 'a' } );
  ar.push( { id: 2, name: 'b' } );
  ar.push( { id: 3, name: 'c' } );
  ar.push( { id: 4, name: 'd' } );
  
  // finalizing object
  super( ...ar );
 }
 
 Foo() {
  console.log( 'foo' );
  return this.filter( item => item.id > 2 );
 }
}

let t = new TestClass();
console.log( t.Foo() );
```

It is simpler version of what I've already written. My app worked up till now, but stopped the moment I needed to filter data in my extended array.
I've found out, that the problem is that calling a filter function on an object of my class internally calls constructor. The above code shows that example.
Is there any way to bypass this issue, because I can't call constructor again at this point. Also, I've found out (using this simple `TestClass`) that actual output is not what I would expect - I get an array of 4 items with id's 3, 4, 3, 4. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: I'd imagine it's calling the constructor again because the `.filter()` method creates a *new* array.

Comment: I would advice to use `let ar` as your array and not extend the base Array. And foo() can the return `this.ar.filter()`.

Comment: Yeah, just before I saw your answer it finally came to me. Instead of creating an Array, it creates another instance of my class.

Comment: @Shilly I was going to do that in my first version, but I wanted to try to play with it a bit more (as I don't use JS too much, wanted to learn a bit) and give objects of this class an "indexer" ( object[i] ), but failed miserably. So I went with extending Array instead of using it internally.

Comment: [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) provides a way to return not another instance of the derived class but for .e.g. in this case an `Array` instance again.

Comment: If you want to just return a simple Array, `return new Array().concat(this).filter(`,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) provides a way to return not another instance of the derived class but for .e.g. in this case an `Array` instance again.

```js
class TestClass extends Array {
  constructor() {
    console.log( 'constructor' );

    let ar = [];
    ar.push( { id: 1, name: 'a' } );
    ar.push( { id: 2, name: 'b' } );
    ar.push( { id: 3, name: 'c' } );
    ar.push( { id: 4, name: 'd' } );

    // finalizing object
    super( ...ar );
  }
  static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }

  Foo() {
    console.log( 'foo' );
    return this.filter( item => item.id > 2 );
  }
}

let t = new TestClass();
let a = t.Foo();

console.log('a : ', a);
console.log('(a instanceof Array) ? ', (a instanceof Array));
console.log('(a instanceof TestClass) ? ', (a instanceof TestClass));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. I don't know why I did not thought that it would create instance of my extended class instead of basic Array.

Answer (score 6):

According to the spec,

[Array.filter](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter) says

> 5. Let A be ? ArraySpeciesCreate(O, 0).

(here, `O` is the original array and `A` the result)

and [ArraySpeciesCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate) says

> 5. Let C be ? Get(originalArray, "constructor").

In layman's terms, `X.filter` creates a new object and applies `X`'s constructor to it. That's why your constructor is called again.

In general, this design needs to be fixed. Your `TestClass` extends `Array`, now, if you replace `Array` with `TestClass` in the whole application, would it behave the same? Obviously not, which means that your `TestClass`  violates a fundamental OOP principle, so called LSP, and should be redesigned (for example, by aggregating an array instead of extending it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Peter's answer solves my problem, but your's answer directly answers question from topic. I can agree that the way I am trying to write this class might not be very good, but I am not a pro developer and just trying to learn a bit of newer features of JavaScript. My initial intention was to have that array stored internally, but I failed to do other stuff I wanted in that class. I'll surely keep that in mind next time.

Comment: " I failed to do other stuff I wanted" - feel free to post a new question, we'll be glad to help.