# Array map calls the constructor of a class that extends Array instead of calling Array constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays

Calling `map()` on an instance `text` of `ConsoleText` class that extends `Array` results in a `ConsoleText(text.length)` call (constructor input: 2 in the last line).
How to fix it so that `text.map()` calls Array constructor instead? Or it is a feature of inheritance?

EDIT: [found an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597292/19612346)

```
'use strict'

let initializingText = true;

class ConsoleText extends Array {
  constructor(strings) {
    console.log('constructor input:', strings);
    if (initializingText) {
      super(...strings);
    } else {
      super('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5');
    }
  }
}

let text = new ConsoleText(['a', 'b']);   // constructor input: (2) ['a', 'b']

console.log('text:', text);   // text: ConsoleText(2) ['a', 'b']

initializingText = false;   // switch to escape error destructuring a number

console.log(text.map(() => 'q'));   // constructor input: 2
                                    // ConsoleText(5) ['q', 'q', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

Comment: I can confirm this in Firefox. My guess is the map method calls its own classes constructor instead of using a hardcoded `Array` one. You can simply overwrite `Array.prototype.map` with your own implementation, it's a really simple method anyway.

Comment: @ScottSauyet edge 104

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in javascript filtering an object of a class that extends an Array calls it's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597062/why-in-javascript-filtering-an-object-of-a-class-that-extends-an-array-calls-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) accepts two different types of arguments:

- `new Array(element0, element1, /* … ,*/ elementN)` - list of elements to create new array
- `new Array(arrayLength)` - array length, it will create an empty array then.

So when you call [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it will create a new array with the same instance class, pass array length into constructor and then will use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to update that array. That is the reason why `map` logs array length in your case.

Furthermore, I do not recommend extending default data structure cause it can be really confusing. Maybe in your case you can just create a simple function, that returns generated array?